# Returning string from C# to C++ using Unmanaged Exports returns numbers

Tags: c#, c++, return-type, unmanagedexports

I have a function in C# that I am calling from C++ using [Unmanaged Exports](https://www.xinterop.com/index.php/unmanaged-exports/). The passed string is received correctly in C# but the returned string in C++ is shown as numbers like 5073480. What could possibly be wrong here? I need to get the string back in C++. Following is the code

C++ code:

```
using Testing = wchar_t*(__stdcall *) (wchar_t* name);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("CSharp.dll");
    Testing performTest = reinterpret_cast<Testing>(GetProcAddress(mod, "testing"));
    wchar_t* d_str = L"JS";
    wchar_t* result = performTest(d_str);
    std::printf("Result from c#: %d\n", result);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

C# code:

```
[DllExport(ExportName = "testing", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static string PassStringInOut([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string name)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received string is: "+name);
    return string.Format("Hello from .NET assembly, {0}!", name);
}
```

Comment: The printf format specifier is wrong.  Use %ls instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems here.

The format string is wrong. To print a Unicode string using ASCII version of printf, the format specified is `%S` (note the capital `S`).

Second, you introduced a memory leak here. After you’re done using the string in C++, you must free the memory by calling [CoTaskMemFree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cotaskmemfree) (assuming you’re writing code for Windows).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Yes I am writing code for Windows. Thanks for pointing it out, I am working on the memory leak issue